# WPF: Databinding and the keypress handlers

Tags: wpf, binding

This is my textbox:

```
<TextBox TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding PriorityScore, StringFormat=N2}"       
         Name="PriorityScoreBox" TextChanged="PriorityScoreBox_TextChanged" />
```

When I click on the Save button everything works fine.

When I press Control-S, it doesn't save the pending changes in the textbox. This is done via a page-level key press handler.

I cannot use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` because it interfers with the string formatting. (The user types "4" and the box auto-changes to "4.00".)

Perhaps there is a way to commit the outstanding changes in a key press event?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub PriorityScoreBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
  If e.Key = Input.Key.S And CBool(e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers And ModifierKeys.Control) Then
      Dim bx As BindingExpression = CType(sender, TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)
   bx.UpdateSource()
 End If
End Sub
```